# Java method returning hashcode ,i want a single value back

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I keep getting back a hash value when trying to return a single value i have tried a number of different thing yet to luck

```
private static void displayHighestScores(int[] walkingScores, int[] groomingScores,
        int[] overAllscore, int  numberOfCompetitors)
{
    findMax(walkingScores, groomingScores,  overAllscore, numberOfCompetitors);
    printTitle();
    System.out.println("The best walking score is " + walkingScores.toString());
    System.out.println("The best grooming score is " + groomingScores.toString());
    System.out.println("The best overall score is " + overAllscore.toString());



}
private static int findMax(int[]walkingScores,int[] groomingScores,int[] overAllscore, int numberOfCompetitors){
    int i;
    int lowest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfCompetitors; i++){
        if (walkingScores[i] > lowest)
            lowest = walkingScores[i];
    }
    return i;

}


it is printing out this :
```

### Village Dogs Competition 2014

The best walking score is [I@2a08d18c

The best grooming score is  [I@28f553e3

The best overall score is [I@2567117

Press Return to continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is fine, you're just printing it out wrong.

Instead of calling `.toString()` on arrays, use `Arrays.toString(array)`, e.g.

```
System.out.println("The best walking score is " + Arrays.toString(walkingScores));
```

Comment: im trying to get the highest value to return, where as this returns the whole array. any tips?

Comment: Um, it looks like your `findMax` method should only take a single array, should return the maximum value from that array, and you should be printing `findMax(walkingScores)`, and so on.

Comment: your saying something such as... system.out.println(findMax(walkingScores)); should work?

Comment: Yes, if you write `findMax` correctly.